# Does Qt provide a way to access the public/shared user folder?

Tags: c++, qt

Currently, my application runs on both Windows and Mac and uses `QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::ConfigLocation);` to get a path to save certain files.

It looks like all the StandardPaths return only user specific directories.

Windows: (e.g. C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/MyApp)

Mac: (e.g. /Users/User/Library/Preferences)

Is there a way to access the public/shared user folder (e.g. C:/Users/Public)?

Comment: I don't think this concept transfers across operating systems. That in itself would be a good reason why it's not there at all.

Comment: The *second* result of `QStandardPaths::standardLocations`, if it exists, seems to be a shared location on desktop OSs.